# Set email as username in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using ASP.NET Core RC1 with ASP.NET Identity and I have the following:

```
User user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("myname@mydomain.com");

SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, "mypassword", true, false);
```

With this the result is a success ... But if I simply try:

```
SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("myname@mydomain.com", "mypassword", true, false);
```

It fails ... I know that PasswordSignInAsync accepts the username as the parameter and not the email ... But how to use the email as username?

Do I need to make the extra call to get the user every time I need to authenticate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PasswordSignInAsync [has 2 overloads](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/SignInManager.cs) one that takes a TUser and one that takes a username.

The one that takes a username is simply calling the one that takes a TUSer, since you can already get the user by email why not just pass in the user?

here is the code from the overload that takes a username, you can see it does nothing but call the other one after looking up the user by username

```
    public virtual async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return SignInResult.Failed;
        }

        return await PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
    }
```

the only other way you could do it is to implement a custom UserStore that looks up the user by email as if it were username

Comment: I am getting the use by email first just for testing because I do not need it ... That is why I wanted to use PasswordSignInAsync with email directly to avoid an extra call to the database.

Comment: there is no extra call since there is also a call with username